# How to get "[DEBUG] Executing command line:" when running exec-maven-plugin java

Tags: java, maven, command-line, mojo, exec-maven-plugin

I am running someone else's `pom.xml` which has:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>${main.class.remote-query}</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run `mvn` with `-X` the actual command that is executed is not displayed. Changing `java` to `exec` will probably provide it but I am curious if there is a way to see the full command line when using java.

Answer (score 0):

According to [`ExecJavaMojo.html`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/xref/org/codehaus/mojo/exec/ExecJavaMojo.html#L257) is should say something like: 'Invoking ' + the class to call + main-method + its arguments. However, it is executed within the same JVM and not from commandline.

Comment: Thanks. In the maven DEBUG output I see "[DEBUG] Invoking : " but it does not show the full command line which can be copied and pasted into a CMD screen to run. I am looking for something similar to the logged message when source code is compiled.

Comment: Because it is not executed like that. I guess you're looking for something like `java [-options] com.foo.bar.Main [args...]`. Best option you have is described as http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html

Comment: That documentation is currently not available. What kind of option are you implying?

Comment: Plugin documentation has been moved to http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/

Comment: It wasnt printing arguments in my case, so I looked into ExecJavaMojo.html. It turns out, that it will only print the arguments if getLog().isDebugEnabled() return true.